# How do you identify files coming from multiple html file inputs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

I currently have a form with multiple file inputs:

```
Resume: <input type="file" id="resume" name ="files" /><br />
Cover Letter: <input type="file" id="coverLetter" name ="files" /><br />
```

and in my back end:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Apply(ApplyModel form, List<HttpPostedFileBase> files) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(form);
    }
    else if (files.All( x => x == null))
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("Files", "Missing Files");
       return View(form);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
             {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                <!--- HERE -->
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how do I determine if the file is from id resume or coverLetter in the spot at the commented HERE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't identify it. You need to use different names:

```
Resume: <input type="file" id="resume" name="coverLetter" /><br />
Cover Letter: <input type="file" id="coverLetter" name="resume" /><br />
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Apply(ApplyModel form, HttpPostedFileBase coverLetter, HttpPostedFileBase resume)
{
    ... now you know how to identify the cover letter and the resume
}
```

and to avoid lots of action parameters use a view model:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    public ApplyModel Form { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase CoverLetter { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Resume { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Apply(ApplicationViewModel model)
{
    ... now you know how to identify the cover letter and the resume
}
```

Comment: Thanks... was wishful thinking I guess.